# How do you undo floating mode for the logcat window in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

While fiddling with the layout in Android Studio I somehow turned my logcat window into a floating window. I cannot for the life of me restore it to docked mode.

[image: logcat is floating]

I would prefer to not have to rebuild the project from scratch, but cannot find anything obvious in `.idea/workspace.xml`.

Answer (score 43):

### Mac OS X answer

Seems the OP is running into this issue on some flavor on Linux. For people with OS X, see this answer.

#### Option 1

If you select the little cog icon at the top right of the floating window, and deselect floating mode, it should pop back to pinned mode:

[image]

#### Option 2

If you don't see the little cog, you can also make sure that the floating logcat window is selected, and then go to Window-> Active Tool Window-> Floating Mode

[image]

Comment: There is no cog on the actual logcat window. There is a cog on the window headed "Android DDMS", but changing the mode in that menu seems to have no effect on where the logcat window appears. When I go to Window -> Active Tool Window, the options Pinned Mode etc are all greyed out so cannot be selected. My set up looks much more like the OP's. Is your screenshot from a Mac?

Comment: Yeah I'm on a Mac, sorry :/

Answer (score 38):

You can drag and drop it back. 
But you need to be dragging the Tab, not the whole window.
I fought with it for 3 days before figuring it out :)

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: That Android Studio thing is horrible.  I wouldn't have had a clue without this answer.  It still took me about an hour of fiddling about with it.  At one point I had Android Device Monitor as a completely seperate window like the previous versions of Studio. It was crazy.  You have to make it float and grab the tab like you said and tie it to the left and then tie it to the bottom finally appears. Terrible.

Comment: That was incredibly too difficult to figure out.

Comment: Thanks for saving life. This was to annoying to figure out.

Answer (score 9):

To sum up the Dave Cole's answer: all you need to do is:

1. Open the `Android Studio` directory.
2. Find the file `.config/options/runner.layout.xml`, open it with some text editor.
3. Find the following piece of code:

   `<ViewImpl>
       <option name="ID" value="Android Logcat" />
       <option name="minimizedInGrid" value="false" />
       <option name="placeInGrid" value="right" />
       <option name="tabIndex" value="0" />
       <option name="window" value="1" />
   </ViewImpl>`
4. And change the `"window"` option's value to 0: `<option name="window" value="0" />`.

Save the file, now your logcat window is in docked mode.

Comment: Thank you. It's fixed. I can't tell you how relieved I am that it's back to normal. I can't award bounty for 23 hours, but as long as it keeps working for that time, the 100 points are yours. Thanks!

Comment: @pbabcdefp Actually, there's another way, easier too. Click, hold and drag `Logcat` tab (not the floating window's title-bar!) back into Android DDMS view, next to ADB logs. It should snap right back in there.

Comment: for mac user : Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio/options

Answer (score 3):

I just realised that the settings controlling the window layout are not stored in the project because the layout was broken for all projects.  I was able to fix the problem by doing this:

```
$ cd ~/.AndroidStudio/config
$ grep -r ddms
$ vi options/runner.layout.xml
```

Then I modified the Logcat configuration to look like this:

```
  <ViewImpl>
    <option name="ID" value="Android Logcat" />
    <option name="minimizedInGrid" value="false" />
    <option name="placeInGrid" value="right" />
    <option name="tabIndex" value="0" />
    <option name="window" value="0" />
  </ViewImpl>
```

The important change was the `window` option.

Comment: I've encountered the same problem. Where do I have to enter that code?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to press Shift + F12. It will restore your view to the Android Studio default view. Or go to Window -> Reset to default.

Answer (score 1):

When floating mode is selected (checked), the docking mode and pinned mode options disappear. simply uncheck the docking mode by right clicking on the logcat tab and click on floating mode and the logcat state will be back to docking mode.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the top rated answers above I still couldn't resolve the issue. Turns out it was a project specific setting. I fixed it by modifying my project's workspace.xml file located in my project's `.idea` folder. In that file look for the element

```
<component name="ToolWindowManager">
```

Under that will be the node:

```
<window_info id="Logcat">
```

change the type of that node from `FLOATING` to `DOCKED`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to delete the runner.layout.xml file under your personal androidstudio config folder (.AndroidStudio\config\options), if you don't need to remain a special IDE layout setting.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and this is how I resolved it:

Simply click on the corner of the icon of logcat (Android-like icon at the top-left corner) and then drag to where you want to place it.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Android Monitor tab, select pinned mode and docked mode. Unselect other modes. My runner.layout.xml file was showing window value 0, so i tried this method it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Settings icon on the top right of the Terminal Window, from the drop-down select Split Mode, Pinned Mode, Dock Mode. This will pin it to the bottom window. Unselect Split Mode if you want it grouped with the other bottom windows.

Answer (score 0):

select window
**Select Default layout** or press  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>F12</kbd>

It fixes the **logcat window** at the bottom.