# Dock logcat window on a side of Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, logcat

I hope not to be off topic.

I consider Android's logcat window in Android Studio horribly annoying, even working with two monitors.

To open the logcat window, that often needs to be fairly big, my procedure is:

- click below on "Android Monitor"
- select the current running device (one time only)
- click on that tiny and almost invisible icon on the extreme right
- reduce again the Android Monitor that I don't need at all
- most of the times resize and move the logcat window.

Whenever a change has to be written or something has to be seen on the emulator, the logcat window **needs to be moved or closed**, because it stands on top of every window, and this leads to perform that same sequence again after maybe few minutes.

Debugging using logcat becomes a pain, made of opening and closing that same window dozens of times.

I want that window to popup or dock automatically with one single icon click or with a key combination from the right, or the left, like for example "Android Model", without getting crazy every time. **One click shows it, one click hides it**.

Is it possible?

Comment: Take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28909485/how-do-you-undo-floating-mode-for-the-logcat-window-in-android-studio
It helped me resolve it.